# Can you call a Solidity contract method with only Metamask?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, metamask

I’m wanting to use Metamask in my app to let users pay a fixed ETH fee (plus gas) to call a method from my Solidity contract. I looked at the Metamask documentation and the `eth_sendTransaction` method seems close to what I need; `eth_sendTransaction` would certainly allow me to request ETH from a user, but the “data” parameter is a bit confusing.

The Metamask docs say:

> data is optional, but used for defining smart contract creation and interaction

and

> also used for specifying contract methods and their parameters.

So “data” represents my method and its parameters, but how does Metamask (or `window.ethereum`, rather) know the contract whose methods I’m trying to call?

Don’t you normally have to provide a contract address and ABI/JSON in order to interact with a deployed contract? In short, is it possible to do what I’ve described with just Metamask alone? Or do you have to do other client-side setups in order to call a method with `eth_sendTransaction`?

Edit: by the way TylerH, the answer involved using web3.js. Maybe don't edit people's posts unless you know what the hell you're talking about. Just a thought...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you will need the contract abi in order to get the information you need to include in the data that you're passing to the contract.  There are also a few other things that you will need to accomplish this:

First you will need to make sure you download the `ethers.js`, and `@alch/alchemy-web3` npm libraries into your application.  Secondly you will need a provider API key from a platform like `Alchemy` in order to communicate with the contract abi. Lastly, you will need the contract abi which can be found at the bottom of the contract section of etherscan.  There is plenty of information on how to obtain these things online, so I won't go over how to configure them here.

Once you have these, you are ready for the next step.

I suggest creating this in a utilities file somewhere in your applications file system, but the idea is this:

```
const alchemyKey = process.env.ALCHEMY_KEY;
const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = process.env.CONTRACT_ADDRESS;
const { createAlchemyWeb3 } = require("@alch/alchemy-web3");
const web3 = createAlchemyWeb3(alchemyKey);
const contractABI = require('../contract-abi.json');
export const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, CONTRACT_ADDRESS);

export const yourMethod = () => {
 if(window.ethereum.request({method: 'eth_requestAccounts'})){
  const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
  const signer = provider.getSigner();
  const address = await signer.getAddress();

  const tx = {
   from: address,
   to: CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
   value: "some wei value", // this is the value in wei to send
   data: contract.methods.YOUR_CONTRACT_METHOD_HERE().encodeABI()
  }

  const txHash = await window.ethereum.request({
   method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
   params: [tx]
  });

  // do something with your transaction hash here
  console.log({txHash});
 }else{
   console.log('user must connect wallet');
 }
}
```

So the value that is populated in the data field of our transaction comes from calling the method that we are trying to invoke in our contract.  This is encoded, and then we pass this information along with the rest of our transaction data.

This is a very short and brief description as to what this does, and I hope this is what you're looking for.  If you need any more help I'm always available to chat on Twitter @_syndk8.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Sorry, this just dawned on me, but how do we use this in the browser? myMethod is meant to be run in the browser, but it references back-end data (our environment variables, contract-abi.json, etc.) P.S. I tried to message this over Twitter, but couldn't.

Comment: @EthanPenrod you will need to call this method from your front end.  Once you do that, it should automatically pull up MetaMask (if it's installed) and all of the information should already be populated to confirm the transaction.

Comment: This example just used the "raw transaction" method, however it will be very pain if you want to pass some parameter to the contract method( e.g. pass an array of string)

Comment: @Siwei not necessarily.  In that situation I would compile the array of strings in a different constant variable and then just pass that variable in as your parameter.  I don't think there's any getting around that.